# Azure Service Bus Exception : Cannot allocate more handles. The maximum number of handles is 4999

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

**I have n numbers of azure functions getting invoked and sending messages to topics. Meanwhile I get below exception:**
Cannot allocate more handles. The maximum number of handles is 4999. (QuotaExceeded), StackTrace : at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.CreateSendingLinkAsync(String entityPath, String identifier, AmqpConnection connection, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.OpenSenderLinkAsync(String entityPath, String identifier, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpSender.CreateLinkAndEnsureSenderStateAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout) at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout) at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpSender.CreateMessageBatchInternalAsync(CreateMessageBatchOptions options, TimeSpan timeout) at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpSender.<>c.<<CreateMessageBatchAsync>b__16_0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.RunOperation[T1,TResult](Func`4 operation, T1 t1, TransportConnectionScope scope, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.RunOperation[T1,TResult](Func`4 operation, T1 t1, TransportConnectionScope scope, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpSender.CreateMessageBatchAsync(CreateMessageBatchOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusSender.CreateMessageBatchAsync(CreateMessageBatchOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

What steps should I take up to address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You're exceeding the number of concurrent connections on a namespace, which is [5,000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas#messaging-quotas). Reduce the concurrency on your functions and check if there are other consumers/producers connecting to the namespace, taking up all the connections.

Comment: Thanks @Sean. As per the document it talks about limitations on 5000 concurrent TCP connections. So does it mean I can have more than 5000 concurrent REST API operation?

Comment: REST is for management operations only. You still will be throttled.